# Passing RGB Color to .setBackgroundColor

Tags: java, swing, colors, hex

I have some color, coded in `RGB` format: `121E31 hex`. How do I **pass** this color to **Java's `Color` class**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is normally done using [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Color color = Color.decode("0x121E31");
```

Answer (score 2):

The RGB value of your "121E31" color is : 18,30,49

For this refer http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php

Now this RGB value can be added using java class as follows

Color c = new Color(18,30,49);

Comment: I know that, I was just tired and could not find .decode method in docs! Otherwise, thank you!